# IB (Instant Bloomberg) chat transcript via API

Tags: api, bloomberg, blpapi

I have a Bloomberg terminal running on my PC.

Is there a way of reading chat transcript from my own application ?
For example I am using Bloomberg API from C#, but developer's guide does not mention anything about "Instant Bloomberg". I use BBG API for MD purposes, so I am quite familiar with this API, however can't find "chat API".

If BBG API is not an option, are there any other possibilities ?

I just want to READ from chat, not write (contribute).

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. "HELP HELP" can probably give you a definite answer.

Comment: Probably you are right, I can't find anything. As BBG API is not an option, are there any other options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new IB API introduced by Bloomberg in 2018. This service allows banks to integrate Bloomberg chat with their internal trading apps.

There is an extra cost associated with the use of of IB API.

BBG API does not support chat integration.

Comment: What did you mean by IB in this case? I'm having trouble finding what the api you are referring to is.